# Getting error "MSVCP120.dll missing" when trying to install Qt on Windows 7

Tags: qt

I have Windows 7 Professional SP1, without any Visual C++ or Visual Studio. I have just installed MinGW. I download Qt installer "`qt-unified-windows-x86-2.0.3-online.exe`" and execute it, and I get a popup complaining that `MSVCP120.dll` is missing.  I don't really insist on using MinGW as my compiler; I'd be enclined to download a free version of MS Studio if that will make the whole installation work, and allow me to build.

**Where have I gone wrong?** (Ah, I want to link a snippet of the popup error window, but I can't figure out how!)

Comment: I think you need the visual studio runtime installed. You can get it from the windows SDK,but it's probably easiest to install visual studio community 2015.

Comment: You need to installed the MICROSOFT VISUAL C++ REDISTRIBUTABLE FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2013 before installing Qt 5.6.0. [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784)